# Gatsby + React building static HTML error

Tags: reactjs, node.js, webpack, compiler-errors, gatsby

Im making a website with Gatsby & React where I use webgi to render a 3D model; I need to build that project but I have a html compilation error with webgi and node-fetch, here is the error :

```
 ERROR #95313  HTML.COMPILATION

Building static HTML failed for path "/"

See our docs page for more info on this error: https://gatsby.dev/debug-html

  WebpackError: ReferenceError: self is not defined
  
  - bundle.m.js:19 
    [*.fr]/[webgi]/dist/examples/runtime/bundle.m.js:19:819797
  
  - bundle.m.js:19 
    [*.fr]/[webgi]/dist/examples/runtime/bundle.m.js:19:819911
  
  - bootstrap:19 
    *.fr/webpack/bootstrap:19:1
  
  - index.js:96 
    [*.fr]/[node-fetch]/lib/index.js:96:1
  
  - bootstrap:19 
    *.fr/webpack/bootstrap:19:1
  
  - static-entry.js:224 
    *.fr/.cache/static-entry.js:224:27
  
  - index.js:387 
    [*.fr]/[node-fetch]/lib/index.js:387:1
```

I've read that this error can come when I call a `window` or `document` without checking if it exists, but everytime in my project i check it (like that : `const isBrowser = typeof window !== "undefined" && typeof document !== "undefined";`)
But it dont solve the problem at all. I don't understand where is the problem, if someone could help me

If needed here is the code of my WebgiViewer :
WebgiViewer.js

```js
import React, {
    useRef,
    useState,
    useCallback,
    useEffect,
} from 'react';
import {
    ViewerApp,
    AssetManagerPlugin,
    GBufferPlugin,
    ProgressivePlugin,
    TonemapPlugin,
    SSRPlugin,
    SSAOPlugin,
    GammaCorrectionPlugin,
    mobileAndTabletCheck,
    BloomPlugin
} from "webgi";
import gsap from "gsap";
import { ScrollTrigger } from 'gsap/ScrollTrigger';
import { scrollAnimation } from '../../lib/scroll-animation';

const isBrowser = typeof window !== "undefined";

if (isBrowser) gsap.registerPlugin(ScrollTrigger);

function WebgiViewer() {
  const canvasRef = useRef(null);
  const [isMobile, setIsMobile] = useState(null);

  const knownScrollAnimation = useCallback((position, target, onUpdate) => {
        if (position && target && onUpdate) {
            scrollAnimation(position, target, onUpdate);
        }
  }, []);

  const setupViewer = useCallback(async () => {
        if (!isBrowser) return;

        const viewer = new ViewerApp({
            canvas: canvasRef.current,
        })

        const imot = mobileAndTabletCheck();
        setIsMobile(imot);

        /*const manager = */await viewer.addPlugin(AssetManagerPlugin)

        const camera = viewer.scene.activeCamera;
        const position = camera.position;
        const target = camera.target;

        await viewer.addPlugin(GBufferPlugin)
        await viewer.addPlugin(new ProgressivePlugin(32))
        await viewer.addPlugin(new TonemapPlugin(true))
        await viewer.addPlugin(GammaCorrectionPlugin)
        await viewer.addPlugin(SSRPlugin)
        await viewer.addPlugin(SSAOPlugin)
        await viewer.addPlugin(BloomPlugin)

        viewer.renderer.refreshPipeline()

        await viewer.load("/scene.glb")

        viewer.getPlugin(TonemapPlugin).config.clipBackground = true;

        viewer.scene.activeCamera.setCameraOptions({ controlsEnabled: false });

        window.scrollTo(0, 0);

        let needsUpdate = true;

        const onUpdate = () => {
            needsUpdate = true;
            viewer.setDirty();
        }

        viewer.addEventListener("preFrame", () => {
            if (needsUpdate) {
                camera.positionTargetUpdated(true);
                needsUpdate = false
            }
        });

        knownScrollAnimation(position, target, onUpdate);
    }, [])

    useEffect(() => {  
        if (!isBrowser) return  
        setupViewer();
    }, [isBrowser]);

  return (
    <div id='webgi-canvas-container' style={{position: 'absolute', height: '150%', width: '100%', zIndex: -1}}>
        <canvas style={{width: '100%', height: '100%', transform: "scale(.8)"}} id="webgi-canvas" ref={canvasRef} />
    </div>
  )
}

export default WebgiViewer
```

scroll-animation.js

```js
import gsap from "gsap";

export const scrollAnimation = (position, target, onUpdate) => {
    const tl = gsap.timeline();
    
    tl.to(position, {
        x: 7.7573730474,
        y: -3.4542389458,
        z: -1.7132344636,
        scrollTrigger: {
            trigger: '.secondary-page',
            start: 'top bottom',
            end: 'top top',
            scrub: 2,
            immediateRender: false
        },
        onUpdate
    });
}
```